# How to restore bootloader or bootsector for Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, linux, boot, bootloader, bootsector

I've restored NTFS containing **Windows Vista**. But the **bootloader or bootsector got corrupted**.

How can i **detect what of them got corrupted**?

How can i **restore bootloader** if it's corrupted?

How can i **repair bootsector** if it's corrupted?

All of these things should be done **from linux** or from bootable CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from Windows installation DVD, choose to repair your PC, choose recovery console and then type in "bootrec /fixmbr", next type "bootrec /fixboot" just for being shure that's everything was taken into consideration. That's Vista way. Win 7 way is to type in "bootsect /nt60 SYS".